# Fullcalendar v3 visibleRange, validRange not working properly

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am trying to show visibleRange from 2017-08-15 to 2017-09-03, but on the calendar show's range: 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2. Missing half of the days from the range. But if I set range from 2017-08-10 to 2017-09-01, shows all date's inside the range. 
Here is the image from the range 2017-08-15 to 2017-09-03

[image]

Here is the code I used:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'month',
    fixedWeekCount: true,
    selectable: true,
    visibleRange: {
        start: '2017-08-15',
        end: '2017-09-03'
    },
    validRange: {
        start: '2017-08-15',
        end: '2017-09-03'
    },
    disableDragging: true,
    editable: true,
    events: [
        {
            title : '55.000 Qmiles',
            start : '2017-10-13'
        },
        {
            title : '55.000 Qmiles',
            start : '2018-04-08'
        }
    ]
});
```

The reason why I need this is to create a 15-days calendar, when you click NEXT it will show next 15 days instead of the full next month. visibleRange is the way i found it could work, but I got this "bug" since sometimes the range will not show all days.

Comment: What you're seeing (in terms of days greyed out) is controlled by validRange, not visibleRange. visibleRange has no effect on the month view, whose layout is essentially fixed and unchangeable (apart from the fixedWeekCount setting). This should probably be made clearer in the documentation, but if you think about how the month view works and  is laid out, it should be fairly easy to work out that it's unlikely to do anything.

Comment: But anyway, why do you need/want this? Why not show a whole month at once? Easier for the user, they don't have to click as many times. Since you're using month view, it doesn't take up any extra screen space (because like I said above, the layout of the view is fixed). All you're doing with this idea is reducing the amount of information available to the user, without reducing the amount of screen space. As far as I can see, that has no benefit to anyone, especially the user, who has to work harder to find information.